# How to execute function at data source level (and in turn bypass Catalyst)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Apache Spark™ provides a pluggable mechanism to integrate with external data sources using the DataSource APIs. These APIs allow Spark to read data from external data sources and also for data that is analyzed in Spark to be written back out to the external data sources. The DataSource APIs also support filter pushdowns and column pruning that can significantly improve the performance of queries.

In addition to this I want to know if Apache spark also provide ability (or interface) 
for data sources which are able to execute functions (native or user defined) natively ?

We have a proprietary data source, and it can give results to functions like max(), min(), size() etc.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** No, that's not possible.

Spark SQL uses functions as a more developer-friendly interface to create Catalyst expressions that know what to generate when given an `InternalRow` (zero, one or more rows per what's available and whether the expression is a user-defined function or user-defined aggregate function, respectively).

`DataSource` does not interact with `Column` (or Catalyst expression in particular) or vice versa in any way. They are separate.

To get very low-level, you could review [Max](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/Max.scala#L27) Catalyst expression yourself and learn what and when is generated at execution time.